# How can I update ogr2ogr to include the PostgreSQL driver?

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql, ogr2ogr

I'm trying to use ogr2ogr to upload a shapefile to a remote PostGres installation. When I ran this command:

```
celenius:~ celenius$ ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL PG:"host=255.34.00.00 user=postgres dbname=mydb password=***" Dropbox/data/roads.shp;
```

I got the following error message:

```
Unable to find driver `PostgreSQL'.
The following drivers are available:
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
 ...
  -> `SVG'
  -> `CouchDB'
  -> `Idrisi'
  -> `ARCGEN'
  -> `SEGUKOOA'
  -> `SEGY'
```

(I omitted some of the drivers as they are not relevant). Is there a way that I can update ogr2ogr to include PostgreSQL? I'm using a Mac with OS 10.7.4

Answer (score 24):

Using Homebrew you should:

> brew install gdal --with-postgresql

or with older versions of gdal:

> brew install gdal --with-postgres

if you have already installed gdal with brew before but without postgresql support, just

> brew uninstall gdal

Comment: a small correction: `brew install gdal --with-postgresql`

Comment: Will QGIS still work with the homebrew GDAL?

Comment: @Simbamangu Sure: homebrew is just a package manager, so the GDAL versions it distributes are the same you can build yourself from source

Comment: Have you actuall tested Kyngchaos's QGIS install with homebrew GDAL? His version may not link with homebuilt versions of other libraries!

Comment: Well it used to work but something seems to be changed with dependencies.. see this Q&A: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79251/osx-10-9-qgis-2-0-1-missing-osgeo-module

Comment: How would you proceed on a windows machine? Ideally using a virtualenv

Comment: what is solution for windows please?

Comment: This now seems to return `gdal: this formula has no --with-postgres option so it will be ignored! ` and/or `gdal: this formula has no --with-postgresql option so`

Answer (score 5):

Save yourself some pain and use the [Kyngchaos packaged binaries/frameworks for OSX](https://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/).GDAL-Complete is the one you are looking for.

Another option is to use [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh).

Comment: AFAIK this is what I used. I didn't install it any other way.

Comment: Does this file exist: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries/libpq.dylib and what does the 'which ogrinfo' command return from the terminal?

Comment: `which ogrinfo` returns `/usr/local/bin/ogrinfo`. I installed GDAL and others from KyngChaos before installing QGis.

Comment: Does the libpq file I mentioned exist in that location?

Comment: If libpq.dylib is not there (the PostgreSQL client library), the OGR library will not load.

Answer (score 4):

assuming you've compiled gdal from source, just include --with-pg=/path/to/pg_config when you're configuring gdal.

```
./configure -with-pg=/path/to/pg_config ...

./make clean

./make

./make install
```

EDIT: Note that `pg_config` should be in the same directory with your other PostgreSQL binaries, like `psql`, etc..  Also note, this detail from user259060's answer below: you should verify that an appropriate postgresql-server-dev version is installed (e.g. on Ubuntu use `apt list --installed | grep postgresql-server-dev` if not found use `apt-cache search postgresql-server-dev` and install the corresponding package with `sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev`).

Comment: Seems I get "PostgreSQL support: yes" in `./configure` output, but trying to `ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL` gives `ERROR 1: Unable to find driver 'PostgreSQL'`. Also, no `PostgreSQL` in `ogrinfo --formats`

Comment: have you run ldconfig after the installation?

Comment: See the edit to the answer about installing postgresql-server-dev,, that should handle the error.

Comment: I think two hyphens in front of with-pg? As in, `./configure --with-pg=/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin/pg_config`

Answer (score 3):

I got this same message while on Windows.

It was complaining about the type of quotes (single vs. double) I was using around the connection string. Switching the quotes fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is a possibility that you might see something like "PostgreSQL support: no", even though you have configured the source using "--with-pg=/path/to/pg_config"...in that case, run sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-all and then retry.

Answer (score 1):

From reading the [ogr2ogr Vector formats](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/ogr_formats.html) doc, it looks like you need to install the PostgreSQL client library (libpq).

This [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13734/gdal-python-bindings-not-picking-up-ogr-postgresql-driver) seems to give some insight into resolving a similar issue, just with Python bindings.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04 (and possibly other versions), a Postgres wrapper for OGR is available from the package `postgresql-11-ogr-fdw`. This is for version 11 of Postgres, as it needs to match the version of the client.

For the list the different versions of this package, for the different versions of Postgres use the following:

`aptitude search postgres | grep ogr-fdw`