# OSX 10.9 + QGIS 2.0.1 - Missing osgeo module

Tags: qgis, gdal, osx, osgeo, homebrew

Running the following:

- `QGIS 2.0.1` (via [Kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis))
- `OSX 10.9`
- `GDAL/OGR 1.10.1` (via Homebrew).

Recently, I've become unable to use the OpenLayers plugin, which is complaining that I'm missing the `osgeo module`.

Has anyone else dealt with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you want to use the Kyngchaos's version of QGIS, you should use his version of [GDAL/OGR](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks) (Framework in /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework). This version also installs the Python osgeo module (in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages because QGIS use the Apple Python).
- If you want to use the Homebrew version of  GDAL/OGR (library in /usr/local/Cellar with symbolics links in /usr/local/bin) you should install the osgeo Python module in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages without Homebrew because the Kyngchaos's version of QGIS does not recognize the Homebrew Python version, or use the Homebrew version of QGIS.

You can't mix these two solutions (unless you know UNIX very, very well)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem with homebrew rgdal by

```
    brew uninstall gdal
    brew install gdal --complete --with-postgresql
```

in terminal,
then installing gdal from CRAN back in R.  The `ogrDrivers()` now displays PostgreSQL and I can successfully import PostGIS views and tables with `readOGR()`.