# Ogr2ogr: ERROR 1: Unable to find driver `PostgreSQL'

Tags: postgresql, ogr2ogr, osx

I need to import geojson files into a local PostgreSQL9.6 database on OSX system.

```
ogr2ogr -f 'PostgreSQL' PG:"dbname=crossmap user=duccioa" "multigraph.geojson" -nln paris.multilayer
```

Ogr2ogr gives this error:

```
ERROR 1: Unable to find driver `PostgreSQL'
```

My GDAL2.1 library have been installed using [kyngchaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/files/software/frameworks/GDAL_Complete-2.1.dmg) binary.
I saw there are other posts on the topic but none of them resolved my problem. One issue is that I cannot figure out how to unistall the library (for example to reinstallit with HomeBrew).
The import used to work, I don't understand what went wrong at one point. The only thing I can think of is the installation of the latest version of QGIS 2.18.

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html and http://www.gdal.org/drv_pg.html might be helpful

Comment: On Unix (MacOS/Linux) you can use `gdalinfo --formats` to check your available drivers for rasters and `ogrinfo --formats` for vectors. If PostGres is not listed there you need to reinstall with postgres support: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33346/how-can-i-update-ogr2ogr-to-include-the-postgresql-driver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to the answer in here https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/issues/1291#issuecomment-574170548