# GDAL 202-1500 driver plugin missing

Tags: arcpy, python, gdal, arcgis-10.2, installation

I have a machine setup with Windows 10, ArcGIS 10.2.1 and Python 2.7 from ArcGIS.  I installed GDAL according to [cartometric](http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/). The *gdal-202-1500-core.msi* and then *gdal-202-1500-filegdb.msi*. With Python, when I load from osgeo import ogr, I have only 1 driver available, the NetCDF. According to [www.gdal.org](https://www.gdal.org/ogr_formats.htmll), i should see at least *ESRI Shapefile*, *GeoJSON* and *Mapinfo File* since they are compile by default and *FileGDB* since I added it.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I suggest using `conda` to install GDAL or just a wheel https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ - a whole lot easier with Windows

Comment: According to the post [GDAL Python bindings not picking up OGR PostgreSQL driver](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13734/gdal-python-bindings-not-picking-up-ogr-postgresql-driver?rq=1), I placed the import os with the os.environ... before the import ogr to make sure that the environment variables are well read and I can see all the drives now.

Comment: I also found out that ArcGIS has as the GDAL plugins and data folders under _...\esri\Data Interoperability (x86)\plugins_. Could it be possible to use directly those librairies making the additionnal GDAL installation unnecessary?